# jQuery match partial text of JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, contains

I'm doing a live search results feature for my website. I have a JSON object containing key terms that I'd like to match the value of an input to.

The best solution I could think of for this was to iterate through each term in a loop and look for a partial matches with a jQuery selector. How can I make an if statement like this? For example:

```js
$.getJSON('jsonfile.json', function(data) {
    key = Object.keys(data);
    for(i=0;i<key.length;i++)
    {
        if($(input[value]:contains == key[i].term)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: My apologies for being unclear. I'm using the :contains selector for partial matches on the value of one input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could to if you have very little items (say, a few dozen) is create a regular expression matching any of them:

```
var match = keys.join("|")
var regexp = RegExp.new(match, 'i') // Case insensitive
if($(input).val().match(regexp)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Yes, I know this does not search for *any* input matching the terms, you'd have to know the input element up front, but from your question I assume you want to check a single input element.

Don't know if its faster than looping over all terms and checking one by one, but I think it is and it's definitely more readable.

This can be used in conjunction with jQuery's `grep` or `each` methods:

```
var match = keys.join("|")
var regexp = RegExp.new(match, 'i')

// With grep
var matches = $('input').grep(function(elem, idx) {
    return $(input).val().match(regexp) != null;
})

// Or with each
$('input')..each(function(idx, elem) {
    if ($(input).val().match(regexp) != null) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

The `grep` selects all input fields that match any of the search terms for later use, and the `each` iterates over all elements to operate on them immediately.

Comment: You can tweak the regexp to match any way you want. You could add word boundaries with `\b`, but it won't match partial hits of the original search terms. E.g. it will match 'ape' against an input containing 'grape', but not 'grape' with an input containing 'ape'. Ofcourse, with regular expressions, you can build that too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to build out the `:contains` selector as a string:

```
if($('input[value]:contains("' + key[i].term + '")').length) {
    //do something
}
```

The selector will return all elements where the input contains the term; adding `.length` provides an easy "truthy" value for the if-statement to evalulate (0 items returned == "false" and >0 items returned == "true").

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if `input[value]:contains()` is a valid jQuery selector, because I don't know what text `:contains()` looks at on an input element. You might need to help it out a bit by checking the *value* of each input yourself. You can filter the inputs found down to those where the value contains the term for which you're searching:

```
if ($('input[value]').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val().indexOf(key[i].term) != -1;
    }).length) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Is there a non case-sensitive version of contains?